# grok skip columns issue

Tags: logstash, grok

**Issue** : I have a log file to parse with 84 columns of which 60 are optional. I got the Pattern working but if grok finds a single log line with a missing field it throws an error. In my case 99% of the logs have some field missing.Is there a way I can configure grok to ignore if a field does not have a value (or insert a dummy value or blank) and move to the next column.

There are 84 columns of which 60 are optional. I am trying to use grok to parse the file and was able to do it only if all 84 columns are specified.

> ads     1.0     4572165a-c5b5-420b-851d-dc69d6d73673    20297cab-4b4c-4b55-b1a8-9ddc436a3f08    2014-02-24 23:55:14     953     1979    93215   106241  97170   58881   29926   10939   6852    34      36      3       URL.com/movie_player.php?pid=155&utm_source=ADK&utm_medium=CPC&utm_campaign=test4_pid155&utm_term=78434-2000241          8       3       1012    98.226.166.151  6042    5303    US      IN              527             11      0       7075    7029    -6      11001   12008   1       11300                   0       0       0       1       url.com/movie_player.php?pid=155&utm_source=adk&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=test4_pid155&utm_term=78434-2000241  www.url.com       url.com   11203   65792   0       live.test.com/swf/v4/manager.swf     345550  7.7     USD     0       0       0       0               0               0       25      0       0       60                              0       0       0       0       0       0       1393286114                                      2               0

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I am doing in order to get around the issue. :

Given : 
grok-logstash does not work well with TSV data : https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-1550
Grok is fine with CSV

Workaround  : Wrote a python script to convert a tsv to csv in the filters and then run it through the csv filter

Sample output :

This is what the rubydebug output looks like :

```
             "supply_sample" => "0",
            "diagnostic_code" => "60",
    "logging_diagnostic_code" => nil,
    "billable_cluster_pi_values" => nil,
    "effective_cluster_pi_values" => nil,
```

***Edit python script not needed this is what I am doing now

> find -name "20140224-2310-10_126_94_215-21460.1.gz" | xargs zcat | sed 's/\t/,/g' | nc localhost 3333